# Image preprocessing - Train and test image data are not being read in corresponding order

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, image-preprocessing

- I am trying to train a **CNN** model for an image processing problem statement. - I am facing a major issue in the preprocessing stage, where the train datasets of both `train_rain` and `train_no_rain` are not in the order I wish for them to be. This is affecting the performance of my model, as it is important for my model to ID an image with rain streaks and then the same image without them.
- Any solutions to this issue?
- Here are the samples of what I am trying to imply -

Say after reading the datasets as shown below:

```py
    path_1 = "gdrive/My Drive/Rain100H/train/rainy"
    train_rain = []
    no_train_rain = 0

    gauss_img = []
    for img in glob.glob(path_1+"/*.png"):
      im = cv.imread(img)
      im = cv.resize(im,(128,128))

    #Gaussian Blur
    im_gb = cv.GaussianBlur(im,(5,5),0)
    gauss_img.append(im_gb)

    cv.waitKey()
    no_train_rain+=1
    train_rain.append(im)

    train_no_rain = []
    no_train_no_rain = 0

    path_2 = "gdrive/My Drive/Rain100H/train/no rain"

    for img in glob.glob(path_2+"/*.png"):
      im = cv.imread(img)
      im = cv.resize(im,(128,128))
    cv.waitKey()
    no_train_no_rain+=1
    train_no_rain.append(im)
```

Now I want to read the first images from `train_rain` and `train_no_rain`, AFTER converting them to `numpy` arrays. and I did that using this -

```py
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

first image from `train_rain`

[image: click here]

```py
    plt.imshow(train_rain[1])
```

first image from `train_no_rain`

[image: click here]

```py
    plt.imshow(train_no_rain[1])
```

But ideally, the first image in `train_no_rain` should be:

[image: this]

PS: The datasets have all the images beforehand, it's just that they are not being read in a particular order.

Any sort of help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: @Bilal thanks for the reply, but now the code throws the following error after `for img in imgs:`

`TypeError - NoneType object is not iterable`

Another thing to note is that `print(type(imgs)` returns `<class 'NoneType'>`

Comment: Found this on the internet - and it perfectly works! 

Do this:
`path_1 = "gdrive/My Drive/real_rain_and_rainfree_1000/train/rain"
imgs = glob.glob(path_1+"/*.png")
imgs = sorted(imgs)`

and then use imgs as:
`for img in imgs:`